# Solution to two-dimensional PDE (wave/Klein-Gordon type equation)

Tags: schroedinger-equation, differential-equations, klein-gordon-equation, non-linear-schroedinger

I'm [cross-posting](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4284268/solution-to-two-dimensional-pde-wave-klein-gordon-type-equation) from the Math SE as more people might have relevant knowledge here. I was playing with an optimization problem and ended up reducing it to solving the following PDE:
$$ a^2 xy \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x \partial y} + f = -axy(y+2ax) $$
where $a \in \mathbb{R}^+$ is fixed and $f : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ is unknown. I have no experience whatsoever with PDEs, but noticed I could separate $x$ and $y$ by changing variables $t = (x+y)/2$ and $r = (x-y)/2$, giving
$$ \left(\frac{\partial^2}{\partial^2 t} - \frac{\partial^2}{\partial^2 r} + \frac{4}{a^2(t^2-r^2)} \right) f = g(t,r) $$
for some fixed $g$ (not relevant here). This looks something like the 1+1-dimensional (time + 1D) [Klein-Gordon equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Klein%E2%80%93Gordon_equation)
$$ \left(\frac{\partial^2}{\partial^2 t} - \frac{\partial^2}{\partial^2 r} + m^2 \right) f = 0 $$
except for the rightmost term in the bracket and the RHS of the equation, which both vary with $t,r$ in my case. It also looks a little bit like [the inohomogeneous Helmholtz equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helmholtz_equation#Inhomogeneous_Helmholtz_equation) or the [screened Poisson equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Screened_Poisson_equation) depending on whether $xy > 0$ or $xy < 0$, except they also have a constant rightmost term in the bracket AND have no time-component. I have no idea where to start, having no expertise in PDEs. I tried looking at [the](https://arxiv.org/abs/1411.6988) [following](https://doi.org/10.1140/epjc/s10052-020-7781-5) [papers](https://doi.org/10.1088/2399-6528/ab42c6) but had a hard time following. Any guidance, hints, solutions most appreciated.

Comment: First define $X=\ln |x|$ and $Y=\ln |y|$ and then use $X$ and $Y$ to define $t$ and $r$ as you did. In this way you should obtain exactly the KG equation with source...

Comment: @ValterMoretti Thank you! Do you have a reference on how to solve the KG equation *with* source?

Comment: I also noticed we get the inhomogeneous Helmholtz equation if we instead define $x, y = x' \pm i y'$, but does this make sense given that $f$ is only defined on real numbers?

Comment: @ValterMoretti Would you like to write your comment into an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: done!  Sorry I d not know textbooks in English where these topics are treated within an elementary approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First define $=\ln||$ and $=\ln||$ and then use  and  to define  and  as you did. In this way you should obtain exactly the KG equation with source.